# iOS:Accessing OlderBluetoothDevice below 4.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, external-accessory

Iam developing iphone application that is based on bluetooth .i have developed an application using corebluetooth frame work and tested to connect the external hardware i.e smart watch.By knowing that its not working to detect the devices . I have developed other example by using external accessory framework .its showing no accessories connected .The documentation specifies that the protocols are added to the plist file under Supported external accessory protocols .

my question is :

1)what are the protocols ?from where i can get that ?

2)how can i make the 4.0 bluetooth to detect the lower compatibly devices.

3)IS there any solution to create protocol and place in the plist file

Are there any sample apps for this

Answer (score 1):

Devices that don't use Bluetooth Low Energy/Bluetooth 4.0 must go through the [Made for iPhone (MFi)](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) program and have an Apple licensed identification chip installed before you can connect to them using the External Accessory Framework

Comment: kk After that MFI process .Apple will provide a specific protocol for that  device and that protocol i.e(com.somename.name) we have to place in the plist file.Then only external accessory framework can able to detect the external device .Is this correc?

Comment: Apple doesn't specify the protocol - that is up to you, but once you have been through the MFi program you will get access to a chip that can be embedded into your devices to identify them to iOS

Comment: kk thank u .there are no other possibilities without MFI program

Comment: Not for Bluetooth 2.1